# How to find Azure 'Temporary Storage' drive through powershell script

Tags: powershell

Do we have PowerShell script to find azure 'Temporary Storage' drive.

In general I use below PowerShell script to find the drive information.

```
Get-WmiObject -class Win32_logicalDisk -computername Server1
```

Comment: temporary drive on azure vm is always on drive D unless you move it yourself

Comment: Could you share the PowerShell script to find the drive if it moved.

Answer (score 0):

In azure, the drive that contains "pagefile.sys" is the temp drive. This file is hidden. Use powershell's "Get-ChildItem -force -file" to find the hidden pagefile.sys file.

Now you have the logic, you can construct your cmdlet :)

Answer (score 0):

I set this up based on the volume being called "Temporary Storage". I ended up here looking for a better solution, but here's what I have:

```
$volumes = get-volume
foreach ($volume in $volumes) {
    if ($volume.FileSystemLabel -eq "Temporary Storage") {
        $tempDrive = $volume.DriveLetter+":\"
    }
}
```

This seems to work as well on a few of my test VMs as well.

```
foreach ($partition in get-partition) {
    if ($partition.DiskPath -eq "\\?\ide#diskvirtual_hd______________________________1.1.0___#5&2d5f53a1&0&0.1.0#{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}") {
        $tempDrive = $volume.DriveLetter+":\"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner using @Manjunath Rao's logic.

get-partition | %{ get-childitem -force -file -filter pagefile.sys -Path ("{0}:\" -f $_.DriveLetter) -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue } | select -ExpandProperty PSDrive